# error when opening a site locally. Bitrix

Tags: php, bitrix

I try to open the site to the Bitrix locally, all files and database downloaded, customized configs. but an error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function SetPageProperty() on null in
> /home/rootname/www/site/site_op/index.php on line 26
>
> ```
> $APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "text");
> ```
>
> class $APPLICATION is NULL.

what could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1):

`$APPLICATION` is not a class. It's an instance of `CMain` and it is global variable.

Obviously you call `$APPLICATION` inside of a scope of some function. And this function doesn't know about `$APPLICATION`. In this case add `global` keyword and use it:

```
global $APPLICATION;
$APPLICATION->SetPageProperty("description", "text");
```

Comment: the problem was resolved by including in short_open_tag in php.ini